# Sed delete empty lines after a particular line number

Tags: text-processing, sed, gnu

I am trying to delete all empty lines after line number 3, till the end of  the file:

```bsh
cat ${File}
1

2
3


4

5

5



6
7



8
9


sed -e '3,${s~^$~~g}' ${File}
1

2
3


4

5

5



6
7



8
9
```

**Observation**:  No change in the output.

**Desired Output**

```
1

2
3
4
5
5
6
7
8
9
```

### Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try:

```
sed '4,$ {/^$/d}' infile
```

start from the 4<sup>th</sup> line until end of the file, delete the empty lines.

The problem with your command is that you replace empty line again with empty string in `s~^$~~g` (which is same as `s~^$~~`) and you are not deleting it.

Note: also since you use different delimiter other than default slash `/`, to use this style `~^$~d` you need to escape the first `~` to tell `sed` that is not part of your regex:

```
sed -e '4,${ \~^$~d }' infile
```

see [`man sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) under "Addresses" about it:

> **\c**regexp**c**
> Match lines matching the regular expression regexp.  The **c** may be any character.

---

In case you wanted to delete empty lines as well as the lines containing only whitespaces (Tabs/Spaces), you can do:

```
sed '4,${ /^[[:blank:]]*$/d }' infile
```

Comment: Regarding delimeter `TextWithPipe="Alpha|Beta|Gamma"; ReplacementTextWithPipe="Delta"; echo "${TextWithPipe}" | sed "s|Beta|${ReplacementTextWithPipe}|g"` gives desired output `Alpha|Delta|Gamma`. But according to you, it should not work as I am using a differnt delimiter?

Comment: @Porcupine that's substitution for the `s` command, which is different from what I said. `/regex/` is for regex match and anything other than `/` for that you must escape the first character

Answer (score 7):

Another `awk` solution:

```
awk 'NR<=3||NF' file
```

This will print all lines where either the line number is smaller or equal 3, or which have at least one "field", defined by default as at least one non-blank character. This way, you can also exclude lines that contain no "text" but are only "visually" empty, i.e. that still contain space or tabs.

Answer (score 4):

```
sed '1,3b;/./!d'
```

Branch in range 1,3 or delete if empty.

Answer (score 3):

You were almost there. Just needed to add the following steps.

```
sed -ne '4,${s~^$~~;t};p' < "${File}"
```

- select the range `4,$`
- try the dummy substitution `s/^$//`
- in case the `s///` succeeds, skip to next record `t`
- else fall back n print for either these in-range nonempty lines or all out-of-range lines `};p`

Answer (score 2):

an `awk` solution:

```
awk '((NR > 3 && $0!~/^$/) || NR <= 3) { print }' file
```

Comment: `awk 'NR<3 || /./'` can be simplified to this.